# Enums aren't generated when using ServiceStackVS?

Tags: servicestack

I have following Enum:

```
[DataContract]
    public enum Gender
    {
        [EnumMember(Value = "m")]
        Male,

        [EnumMember(Value = "f")]
        Female
    }
```

Used within following Request:

```
public class AddPlayerRequest : IReturn<AddPlayerResponse>
{
    public string FirstName { get; set; }
    public string LastName { get; set; }
    public string Nationality { get; set; }
    public DateTime Birthdate { get; set; }
    [ApiAllowableValues("Gender", "Male", "Female")]
    public Gender Gender { get; set; }
}
```

When the DTOs are generated using **ServiceStackVS** extension the Gender enum is generated as shown below:

```
    public virtual Gender Gender { get; set; }
```

But the client doesn't know anything about the Gender enum so how should I tackle that?

Comment: The typical way to handle that is to put your DTOs and any types and enums that are required by the service consumers into their own separate library that you reference in your ServiceStack Server application, and the clients can reference in their application. Thus the clients know the values of the enum, and the Service is typed end-to-end.

Comment: In which situations should I use ServiceStackVS?

Comment: You can use ServiceStackVS to setup the project as normal, if you are happy doing it that way. Just ensure you create the `Gender` enum in the Service Model project, rather than Service interface. That way it is available to both the clients and the servers.

Comment: @westbeam87 are you trying to use the "Add ServiceStack Reference" tool in ServiceStackVS, and your question refers to the code generated by that tool? As of v4.0.31 (and the 4.0.32 version currently in MyGet), it seems the generated code is not including enum definitions.

Comment: Note that Demis is working on some patches for this functionality, the latest versions of 4.0.32 on MyGet should fix the issue described here.